gganimate - Values ovelaping during transition
I want to create an animated barplot with the gganimate package. At the top of plot, I want to put the value of the coresponding year. In my dataset, year value is 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010. However, when the animatation is shown, I can see year value is overlap to each other as shown in the below picture:

This is my data file: test.csv
This is my code:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(maps)
library(scales)
library(gganimate)

test_data <- read.csv("test.csv")
male_data <- test_data |> filter(sex_name == "Male") |> group_by(year) |>
  arrange(mean_age_death) |>
  slice_head(n = 10) |>
  mutate(rank_in_year = rank(mean_age_death, ties.method = "first"))|>
  ungroup()

male_faceted_plot <- male_data |>
  ggplot(aes(x = mean_age_death, y = factor(rank_in_year))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(vars(year)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(-50,50),
    breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 10)
  ) +
  geom_text(
    hjust = "right",
    aes(label = country_name),
    x = -5,
    size = 5
  )

male_bar_race <- male_faceted_plot +
  # remove faceting
  facet_null() +
  # label the current year in the top corner of the plot
  geom_text(
    x = 50, y = 10,
    hjust = "top",
    aes(label = as.character(year)),
    size = 10
  ) +
  # define group structure for transitions
  aes(group = country_name) +
  # temporal transition - ensure integer value for labeling
  transition_states(year, transition_length = 1, state_length = 2, wrap = TRUE) 

# basic transition
animate(male_bar_race, nframes = 300, fps = 100, start_pause = 10, end_pause = 10)

How can I fix this?
Thanks,

thanks for your reply. I updated full code and the data file. Please help me check

The parameters nframe (number of frames to render) and fps (frames per second) should be chosen carefully. Below, you will find my proposal.
male_bar_race <- male_faceted_plot +
  facet_null() +
  geom_text(
    x = 50, y = 10, hjust = "top",
    aes(label = year),
    size = 10
  ) +
  transition_states(year, transition_length = 1, state_length = 2, wrap = TRUE) 

nfr <- length(unique(male_data$year))
animate(male_bar_race, nframes = nfr, fps = 1)

Below is the animation with a smooth transition effect.
male_bar_race <- male_faceted_plot +
  facet_null() +
  geom_text(
    x = 50, y = 10, hjust = "top",
    aes(label=sprintf("%4.0f", year)),
    size = 10
  ) +
  transition_reveal(year)

animate(male_bar_race, nframes = 40, fps = 10)


Thanks for your help. With this code, the overlapping is solved but the transition effect also disappears. If I use transition_states(year, transition_length = 0, state_length = 2, wrap = TRUE) , the result will be the same as yours.

@uv_utna Hi. I updated my post by adding a solution with a transition effect. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Thanks for your update, it looks better now
